# A way to get all the actions made in your app, by all users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Given an app (your app) and a certain action it has, is it possible to make a graph call to retrieve all the actions made in the app, by **all** users?

For example,

- A call that allows Spotify to see aggregation of all the "listen" actions made,
- A call that allows Washington Post social reader to get all the "reads" made by its users.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get all the Open Graph Beta actions generated by an app?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8007724/how-to-get-all-the-open-graph-beta-actions-generated-by-an-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this documentation you can request these permissions to read music, news and video.

You can use this to get the data for authorised users for **all** apps that use these actions eg. spotify or on an app by app basis using the call user_actions:APP_NAMESPACE

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#open_graph_perms

From your question you want actions made by all users, which I do not think is possible from the FB API, but you could record the data yourself utilising the above.